How to run the http-pokeapi sample app from Keploy?
I was exploring the Keploy sample apps and couldn't find the documentation for the http-pokeapi sample app in the samples-go repository. I tried to explore a bit, but couldn't find proper solution.
Link: https://github.com/keploy/samples-go/tree/main/http-pokeapi
I'm an absolute beginner in Go lang, so how can I run this app?
